# Как закрыть меню аккордеон с помощью javascript?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Понравилось меню аккордеон http://ruseller.com/lessons/les306/example/index.html.

Вот код:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Меню в виде аккордеона для Вашего сайта</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 10px auto;
    font: 75%/120% Verdana,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.menu_list {    
    width: 150px;
}
.menu_head {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin:1px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background: #333 url(images/left.png) center right no-repeat;
    color:#fff;
}
.menu_body {
    display:none;
}
.menu_body a{
  display:block;
  color:#555;
  background-color:#999;
  padding-left:10px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.menu_body a:hover{
  color: #333;
  text-decoration:underline;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="float:left" >

  <div id="firstpane" class="menu_list">
        <p class="menu_head">Меню</p>
        <div class="menu_body">
        <a href="#">Главная</a>
         <a href="#">Форум</a>  
         <a href="#">Блог</a>   
         <a href="#">Контакты</a>   
          <a href="#">О проекте</a>
        </div>
        <p class="menu_head">Публикации</p>
        <div class="menu_body">
            <a href="#">Новости</a>
         <a href="#">Статьи</a>
         <a href="#">Закачки</a>    
        </div>
        <p class="menu_head">Профиль</p>
        <div class="menu_body">
          <a href="#">Мои друзья</a>
         <a href="#">Мои сообщения</a>
         <a href="#">Мои файлы</a>      
         <a href="#">Выйти</a>      
       </div>
  </div>  
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{

    $("#firstpane p.menu_head").click(function()
    {
        $(this).css({backgroundImage:"url(images/down.png)"}).next("div.menu_body").slideToggle(300).siblings("div.menu_body").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).siblings().css({backgroundImage:"url(images/left.png)"});
    });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Я хочу чтобы это меню закрывалось при помощи javascript, т.е. в случае если у пользователя в браузере отключен javascript меню отображалось в развернутом виде. Если убрать в стилях `.menu_body {display:none;}`, то оно развернется. Как его свернуть при помощи javascript?

Comment: Iranda, с удовольствием. Нажимаю на галку - ничего не изменяется. Наверное отметился. Если нет, то, пожалуйста, сообщите как сделать правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А разве что-то особое надо выдумывать?

```
$("div.menu_body").hide();
```

Comment: Да, работает))). Большое спасибо.

Comment: Велкам! *Пардон, что на чистейшем английском* ;)